# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function. Clonar html e botão Back

Tags: php, javascript, html, pl-sql

Estou tendo um problema no sistema em que preciso fazer um botão para *voltar* e pensei em uma função para clonar usando e uma função para o botão *voltar*.

Mas o problema é que quando faço login no sistema vou para um menu e quando clico em uma opção ele carrega um sub-menu na mesma *grid* , é ali que ocorre toda a interação do usuário, quando clico no voltar ele executa a função *back* volto novamente para o menu, mas se eu tentar acessar um outro módulo as funções não funcionam e retornam este erro:

> Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function.

Código:

```js
var n= 0;
var divClone=[""] ;  

function clone(){
    divClone[n]=$("#grid").clone();
    n++ 
}

function back(){
    n--;
    $(''#grid'').html(divClone[n]);
}
```

Comment: Você está clonando `#grid` e devolvendo o valor para ele?

Comment: Sim pois quando clona ele volta com a chamada das funções e os valores já definidos.
pois o JS fica definido no inicio do HTML e não muda, então quando eu clico em algum botão tem que executar esta função por exemplo`function back()
                 {
                   n--;
                   $(''#grid'').html(divClone[n]);
                 }`

Comment: Você não acha melhor implementar um histórico de navegação ao contrario de ficar clonando o conteúdo diversas vezes? Até porque fazendo um simples teste aqui percebi que você vai inflando o conteúdo de `divClone`, provavelmente após algum tempo isso pode se tornar um problema.

Comment: Inflando porque? Não, pois utilizo PL/SQL para gerar o sistema e por segurança nenhuma pagina e a mesma. Assim quem "escreve o código" é o Banco de dados. E pra diminuir o numero de paginas geradas eu estou modificando para o sistema funcionar apenas atualizado as Div's.

Comment: O trecho `$(''#grid'')` está idêntico ao do seu projeto? Se sim, tem aspas sobrando ai. O correto seria `$('#grid')`.

Comment: Creio que o amigo  @guilhermenagatomo encontrou o problema.